# Normalize smaller than base?

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function

I am trying to solve a programming task and am having some trouble understanding whats going on.

We have to normalize a numbers smaller than the base. For example:

> For the numbers $\{12, 25\}$, Base $10$
> the result should be:
> $12 + 25 * 10 ^ 1 = 262$, which we need to return as $\{2,6,2\}$ (not a problem, I solved this already).

However, for the numbers:

$$\{52, 44, 84\},\text{ Base $2$}$$

I get as the result $476$, so $\{4,7,6\}$, but it's wrong. The output should be:

$$\{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1\}$$

Can anyone explain what mathematical operations needs to be done to get the above result for $52$, $44$, $84$ and base $2$?
The task says: It should normalize each number so that it's smaller than its base.

This is just a small part of the task I have to solve, so you are not doing my homework, if thats your concern.

Edit: I assume the decimal number 476 needs to be converted to the binary system to get the same result?

Comment: Where does this problem come from?

Comment: Yes, you did the arithmetic correctly, but you output the answer in base 10 instead of in base 2.

Comment: @GregMartin got it, i will try to find a way to convert it to any base, as its not only a binary base as the input. Will report back if i could figure it out or not. Thanks for taking the time already everyone!

Comment: If you have the code that outputs $476$, maybe you can share it so that we could see your mistake. The resulting number *is* $476$ and it seems your *output* just was in base $10$ rather than in base $2$ (in which case it would be, indeed, $111011100$). Also, when producing output (judging from the “correct” solution) you are supposed to output the least significant digit first, so even in base $10$ your output should’ve been reversed (i.e. $674$ rather than $476$), if that matters. Does that help?